# Error utilizing RealmDB while unit testing

Tags: android, junit, mockito, realm

I am writing a test for a ViewModel. The function in the ViewModel is this:

```
public void discoverMovies(boolean showLoading) {
   // reset the states to initial states
   moviesLoading.set(showLoading);
   errorViewShowing.set(false);
   emptyViewShowing.set(false);

   mMoviesRepository.getPopularMovies(1)
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Movie>>() {
               @Override
               public void onNext(List<Movie> value) {
                   // show or hide empty view
                   boolean isEmpty = value == null || value.isEmpty();

                   if (!isEmpty) {
                        saveResponse(value);
                       movies.clear();
                       movies.addAll(value);
                   }
                   emptyViewShowing.set(isEmpty);
               }

               @Override
               public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                   errorViewShowing.set(true);
                   moviesLoading.set(false);
                   emptyViewShowing.set(false);

                   errorString.set(getErrorMessage(throwable));
               }

               @Override
               public void onComplete() {
                   moviesLoading.set(false);
                   errorViewShowing.set(false);
               }
           });
}

private void saveResponse(final MovieResponse mainResponse) {
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
      @Override public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmMovie realmMovie = realm.createObject(RealmMovie.class);
        realmMovie.setId(1);
        realmMovie.setMarvelResponse(new Gson().toJson(mainResponse));
      }
    });
}
```

And I test the function above in my test class like this:
Note: Everything works without the Realm aspect. I've confirmed that.

```
@Test
public void getPopularMoviesWithoutError() {
    // given the following movies
    when(mMoviesRepository.getPopularMovies(PAGE)).thenReturn(Observable.just(MOVIES));

    // discover popular movies
    mMoviesViewModel.discoverMovies(true);

    // verify that the repository is called
    verify(mMoviesRepository).getPopularMovies(PAGE);

    // test that the loading indicator is hidden
    assertFalse(mMoviesViewModel.moviesLoading.get());

    // check that the empty view is hidden
    assertFalse(mMoviesViewModel.emptyViewShowing.get());

    // check that the error view is hidden
    assertFalse(mMoviesViewModel.errorViewShowing.get());

    assertTrue(mMoviesViewModel.movies.size() == MOVIES.size());
}
```

And it keeps on giving me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call`Realm.init(Context)`before calling this method.` How can I initialize Realm
to be available

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(` you'll never be able to close that Realm instance... Consider putting `saveResponse` into its own class that you can replace with a different build flavor which doesn't use Realm for unit testing

Comment: @EpicPandaForce First: You said I wouldn't be able to close the Instance. But, the realm doc says "We don't need to close an instance if within the (`executransaction`) block. Second: Please can you elaborate on the separate build flavour. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to close it **within** the block. You do need to close the instance you obtained and then called `executeTransaction()` on, though.

Comment: You can refactor your code to depend on an abstraction of a datasource rather than the concretion Realm. Another option is to consider using Robolectric to provide the context.

Answer (score 3):

I think the error message you are getting is quite clear about what is causing the problem.  You are not calling `Realm.init`.

There are several ways of doing this.  The simplest is the `@Before` and `@After` annotations on the test suite.  You could also use a `TestRule`

Unfortunately, `Realm.init` requires a `Context`.  To get that context, you are going to have to be in some environment that has one.  That means that you will either have to run your tests on a device, as Instrumentation tests or, as @David Rawson suggests, use Robolectric.

Comment: Since Realm doesn't support Robolectric yet, I think he should run his tests on a device

Comment: @Dalinaum so we can't run any of unit tests for Realm at JVM even using Robolectric. Only way to do it use Testing support library and instrumentation tests ?

Comment: thanks I guess for unit test just try other stuff that doesn't depend on Realm.